# ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order

Tags: xml, sas

I need help in a sas program. Pgm:

```
     libname in xml 'xmlpath';
     libname dat 'path';

     data dat.subject;
      set in.subject;
     run;
```

my xml has many subject elements inside table tag. everything is working. It says dat.subject has 1 observation and 2 variables. But when I am trying to print dataset dat.subject, I am not able to.
I used list all; show datasets; show contents; everytime I got Error 180-322: Statement not valid or out of order.

Please note: I am learning sas.

Comment: Also, proc print is not printing anything.

Comment: please update your question with the log (which will show the error message in context)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ods output; /* switch on ODS destination */
proc print data=dat.subject; /* basic syntax for proc print */
run;
```

This should work, if dat.subject was created successfully as you say?

Comment: Hey thanks, because of you it worked. It was printing output but on a .lst file. I have direceted the output to other file using proc printto.